# How to use managed ID to authenticate azure communication services

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-communication-services

The following page explains how to use a managed ID with ACS, but is there any other way to register with the Creating an Azure Active Directory Registered Application, such as the Azure Portal or PowerShell?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/identity/service-principal-from-cli#creating-an-azure-active-directory-registered-application

Comment: Could you explain your use case or what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Can I do the same thing as setting a managed ID in the Azure app service or azure functions linked below? There is no screen to set the "ID assigned to the system" in the ACS menu. Also, regarding Azure PowerShell, it seems that there is no command to set the identity of ACS.　https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it all in the Azure Portal. First, you create the service principal:
[image: Register an AAD app]

Then, you assign permissions to it. Either on the subscription level:
[image: Add subscription level permissions]

Or on the Communication Service resource level:
[image: Add ACS-level permissions]